# Not able to redirect to login page the page gets freezed

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

On running test on test case using IE browser getting page gets freezed

OS: Windows 10
Testcafe version: 1.17.1
Node: 14.2.0
npm: 6.14.4

[image]

Comment: This behavior looks like a bug. It would be better if you [open a new issue in the TestCafe GitHub repository](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml) with [a simple example that reproduces this behavior](https://testcafe.io/402636/faq#how-to-create-a-minimal-working-example-when-you-submit-an-issue).

Comment: I couldn't find any open example for this error